# Multiple unexplained syntax errors in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm receiving a LOT of unnecessary syntax errors with VS2010 and I have no idea where they are coming from. Here are some of the errors being received

[image]

though there are actually even more. This particular file is one I received from someone I'm working with and it works just fine on their system, so it shouldn't be the code, regardless I've attached a portion of the code snippet below that includes a good bit of the syntax errors I don't understand:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
//#include "TwoToFourTree.h"


template<class ItemType>

TwoToFourTree<ItemType>::TwoToFourTree()
{
    rootPtr = new QuadNode<ItemType>();
}//Default

template<class ItemType>
TwoToFourTree<ItemType>::TwoToFourTree(const ItemType& anItem)
{
    rootPtr = new QuadNode<ItemType>(anItem);
} // Default with item

template<class ItemType>
TwoToFourTree<ItemType>::~TwoToFourTree()
{
} // Destructor(needs removal function to be finished)

template<class ItemType>
QuadNode<ItemType>* TwoToFourTree<ItemType>::getRootPtr()
{
    return rootPtr;
}  // Returns root pointer
```

Line 8 from the image starts at the first method declaration (the default constructor). Is there a setting that could be causing all this nonsense? I've searched everywhere and I've got no idea how to approach this.

Comment: Please always post error messages as verbatim text. Images aren't helpful as you see.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can't implement template class member functions in a separate source file. Unless you include the .cpp file instead of the .h, you'll get a ton of unresolved external symbol errors in the linker when you try to use them. With that aside, it seems that the first error is coming from a missing semicolon after the word `template` very early in the file. You might be missing a semicolon at the end of the class declaration in your header file. If that's not the case, can you show us the header?

Comment: `TwoToFourTree<ItemType>` is an error because `TwoToFourTree` is not defined.  The other errors cascade from this.

Answer (score 0):

The #include directive for TwoToFourTree.h is commented out, which is presumably the file where the TwoToFourTree class is defined. Try uncommenting that line.

Comment: That's what I originally did, but that gives me different errors that say "so-and-so function is already defined" for all of the functions of the class because in the .h file I've included the .cpp file.

Comment: @Robert: *"because in the .h file I've included the .cpp file"* - That's usually not what you want. Headers should provide declarations, and compilation units (.cpp files) the implementations. .cpp files should include headers, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

he probably took it out of local directory... same as intellj scala programs or visual studio... files have to be somewhere close .. like c:/users/"desktop name"/documents where your desktop folder would reside in. Most of the time in for scala programs you have to add the library path in project structures or in vs CLR C++ consoles click the main go to project->properties->code Generation ... for file build/debug